# Prove $\frac1{z(1-z)}$ is uniformly continuous on the closed annulus $0<r_1\le|z|\le r_2<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am using the standard delta, epsilon definition to try to prove this, but I am not sure how to break down $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|$.

I have **$$\frac {|z_1^2-z_2^2 + z_2-z_1|}{|z_1z_2(1-z_1)(1-z_2)|}$$** but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What are $r_1$ and $r_2$ relative to $0$ and $1$?

Comment: this is what I have 0<r1<r2<1

Comment: Why haven't you included this information in your question ?

Comment: @DHouse Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer that I posted herein? I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

With $0<r_1<r_2<1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{z_1(1-z_1)}-\frac{1}{z_2(1-z_2)}\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{z_1}+\frac1{1-z_1}-\frac{1}{z_2}-\frac1{1-z_2}\right|\\\\
&\le \left|\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_1z_2}\right|+\left|\frac{z_1-z_2}{(1-z_1)(1-z_2)}\right|\\\\
&\le \left(\frac1{r_1^2}+\frac1{r_2^2}\right)|z_1-z_2|\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $\displaystyle|z_1-z_2|<\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{\frac1{r_1^2}+\frac1{r_2^2}}$

Comment: Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer? I really want to give you the best answer I can.